# HQL syntax problem

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a problem with the following HQL query:

```
select sum(MYTABLE.COUNTER) from (

select count(DISTINCT bi.products.id)  as COUNTER 
                   from BusinessInformation as bi 
                   where bi.informationOwners.id in (100) 
                   and bi.products.id in (10) 
                   and bi.valueAmount not in ('NA')
                   and ((bi.valueType = 'ACHIEVED' and bi.referenceYears.id = 1) or (bi.valueType = 'FINAL_BALANCE' and bi.referenceYears.id = 2)) 
                   group by bi.informationOwners.id                   
)  MYTABLE
```

The compiler reports:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 34
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with the query? I tested the inner query and it works fine.

Thanks, 
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries), not FROM.